# Inverse of DiracDelta at 0 is 99/5?

Tags: inverse, dirac-delta, mathematica

When using Mathematica I've found an interesting result.

```
InverseFunction[DiracDelta][0] == 99/5 (* returns True *)
```

Or the inverse function of the DiracDelta function, when evaluated to 0, (which I'd say that could give us any number), returns 99/5.

If this is really the case, how can we prove it?

Does someone know a formal definition of this inverse?
I ask that because Mathematica only gives an abstract representation of it.

**Edit**

I asked this question here: [Inverse of DiracDelta at 0 is 99/5?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221298/inverse-of-diracdelta-at-0-is-99-5),
on mathematica.stackexchange. We can mark this one as a duplicate now.

Answer (score 0):

Since any $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ "solves $\delta(x)=0$" (with the usual asterisks on such a statement; $\delta$ isn't actually a function), $\delta$ has no unique inverse on $0$, be it $19.8$ or otherwise. I don't know what would cause this bug, but I suggest you report it to Mathematica's developers.